# Laying out circles in a rect

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to workout how to efficiently calculate the layout of a dynamic/random view.

The view will contain a number of circles. Each circle has a predetermined size. These sizes are all between a given maximum and minimum size.

I'm trying to find an efficient way of laying out the circles within a rect with a couple of conditions.

The circles mustn't overlap with the edge of the rect and the circles must have a minimum "spacing" between them.

The first method I came up with is to randomly generate coordinate pairs and place the biggest circle. Then randomly generate more coordinate pairs until a suitable one is generated for the next circle. And the next, and the next, and so on until all are drawn.

The problems with this are that it could potentially take a long time to complete. Each subsequent circle will take longer to place as there are fewer places that it can go.

Another problem is that it could be impossible to layout the view.

I'm sure there must be more efficient ways of doing this but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: is the space you have to arrange them free in your rect or do you ask to just make them compact as possible for it?

Comment: It isn't defined yet. The rect starts empty and will probably have a fixed width. The rect can have any height though. If possible I'd like to make them as compact as possible in the top of the rect and then alter the rect height to fit.

Comment: the formula depends on the number of circles you have to arrange. this is indeed a very complex question. see http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/csq/csq.html what science says to it. :) i think it becomes easier if the circles would have physics like gravitation, because then you have fixed data you can calc on top.

Comment: It could be anything from 1 to 20 or 30 ish. There is no maximum limit to this number but a reasonable maximum expected value would be about 20-30 ish.

Answer (score 0):

The Formula must deal between the smallest possible square they need or from a other point of view, with an arrangement with the smallest possible **density** between the edgepoints. But your problem could be solved by sorting the circles by size and then start with the largest and arrange them step by step to the smallest because the larger are more bulky and the smaller fit easier in small corners by there nature.

**Build triangles of circles**, where 3 circles have a discribing space they use together. This triangle has 3 corners right? :) so messure/calc the angle of that corners and the corner with the nearest 90degree angle should be placed in a square corner, better to say the three circles should be places mirrored so that the circle with the ***fittest 90degree corner*** behind is the one who goes in the corner. If a 4th circle fits into the rest of this triangle, wonderful, if not you place exact this circle in it which is taken minimum outerspace of that triangle. because its not said that the next smaller circle is the one who fit's perfect, which also means you have a stack of not placed circles until one is found who fits better. after you find one you go upwards your circle-stack again and try to fit the next of it in one of the corners or you try to build the next triangle. and here you see how complex this is, damn! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malfatti_circles
But anyway, the more one of this triangles corners is 90° the less space it would take with this 3 circles in it.

**An other concept** could be to think about larger circles like space who leftover a triangle in one of its corners in relation to the rectangle. This triangle has a maximum space availible for a smaller circle. If there is no perfectly fitting circle your taken square-space grows up. So as far as i think about to handle this problem with imagined triangles to compare with fitting circles in it or taking triangle ranges from the square is the solutions base.

Comment: all the circles have a common multiple to each other or if not, the most have, at least two have every time a common multiple. so you could find out which of the circles should be handled with care. if the third is smaller then the leftover of the first two, then there is no problem, if it is larger then the first two leftover - it must take more space from the square.

Comment: So the steps are in an array of size-sorted circles where you campare every third with the two before. also the 4th you can compare with two others where the next larger is the first and all the allready calculated circles are one something like a imagined larger circle or?

Comment: Three circles together give back anytime a `Malfatti` or `Steiner` triangle where one of the corners of this triangle is more or less near a 90degree angle. the more it fits to 90degree the more you can place them in a corner of your rectangle.